# exercise write a Graphics program that draws a pyramid

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java from this book `The Art and Science of Java`

exercise in book [The Art and Science of Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486129) page 129

[image]

> my problem is the pyramid should be centered in the window

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run() {


        for (int i = 0; i < BRICK_IN_BASE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

                int x = BRICK_WIDTH * j ;
                int y = BRICK_HEIGHT * i;

                GRect brick = new GRect(x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                add(brick);

            }
        }

    }



    private static final int    BRICK_WIDTH =30 ;
    private static final int    BRICK_HEIGHT =20 ;
    private static final int    BRICK_IN_BASE = 12;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my problem is the pyramid should be centered in the window

If you mean that you have a fixed area to draw in and the pyramid should be centered in that area:

1. get the maximum width of the pyramid: `BRICK_IN_BASE * BRICK_WIDTH`
2. start at `x = (area.width-pyramid_width)/2`
3. same for the height: `BRICK_IN_BASE * BRICK_HEIGHT`
4. start at `y = (area.height-pyramid_height)/2`

Besides that, note that for each level above the base you would have to add `BRICK_WIDTH/2` to the x offset.

Edit (clarification):

The above points apply to getting the x and y coordinates to start drawing at. Note that

1. with "start at x" I meant the initial x offset. Your bricks' x coordinate would be `x_offset + BRICK_WIDTH * j`
2. the same for start at y
3. for each level you have to increase x_offset by `BRICK_WIDTH/2`, i.e. `int x = x_offset + (BRICK_IN_BASE - i - 1) * BRICK_WIDTH/2 + BRICK_WIDTH * j;` (you're starting at the top, so the level would have to be calculated as (BRICK_IN_BASE - i - 1) in order to get 11 for the top row and 0 for the bottom row).

Comment: The height should be `BRICK_IN_BASE * BRICK_HEIGHT` though

Comment: @thomas thanks man ,, Tried, but not be like a pyramid Become like the triangle

Comment: Tarek11011: I tried your code, without the changes @Thomas suggested. I also got a triangle instead of a pyramid. I can help you if you want, but I think you'd rather solve it yourself. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: @Tarek11011 I'm not sure what you mean with triangle (a 2D pyramid is a triangle as well :) ) - but I guess you get one straight side, correct? Did you increase the x offset by `BRICK_WIDTH/2` per level above the base, like I suggested in my last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to find the offsets for x and y.
The width of the pyramid is BRICK_WIDTH * BRICK_IN_BASE, so you take half the width of the window and subract (BRICK_WIDTH * BRICK_IN_BASE) / 2.
You use the same logic to find the y offset.

int x = xOffset + BRICK_WIDTH * j ;
 int y = yOffset + BRICK_HEIGHT * i;

I'm not familiar with the acm package, depending on how it implements GRect this may still be half a brick off. But you can solve that easily.

Answer (score 0):

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class BrickInTheWall extends GraphicsProgram {

```
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 20;
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 10;
private static final int BRICK_IN_BASE = 10;


public void run(){
```

int w=BRICK_WIDTH * BRICK_IN_BASE + 200, h = BRICK_HEIGHT * BRICK_IN_BASE+200;

for(int a = 1; a <= BRICK_IN_BASE; a++) { 
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) { 
GRect rect = new GRect((w*2) - BRICK_WIDTH/2*a+BRICK_WIDTH * i, 40 + BRICK_HEIGHT * a,BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
add(rect);

```
        }       
    }
}
```

}